C++ array pointer to pointer
// Declaring a variable:
int* buf = new int[max_size];

// Filling in the data:
for (int i = 0; i < max_size; ++i) buf[i] += i;

// We pass it to the function:
process(&buf);

Implementation function:
void process(const int* const* buf)
{
  int a = 0;
  int ch = 1;
  for(int c = 0; c < ch; ++c)
    for (int i = 0; i < max_size; ++i)
      a += buf[c][i]; // ???
}

How and by what rule is my array masquerading as an array of arrays?
a += buf[c][i];
Try here: https://www.programiz.com/online-compiler/2VrwQHT2IG5pE
P S:
I think this is because here &but we pass the address for the const float* const* buf part.
But maybe there is a more academic explanation for this?

In the same way int n = 42; int* p = &n; p[0]++; is legal.

Pointers aren't arrays, arrays aren't pointers. buf is a pointer (that points to the first element of an array).

When c is always 0 (which it is in your code), a += buf[c][i]; is the same as a += (*buf)[i];, if you prefer this syntax.

Please note that when you allocate your "array" with new, it's contents will not be initialized. All elements will have indeterminate values. And in C++, using indeterminate values in any way leads to undefined behavior. And with the code shown, you do that with buf[i] += i.

Sidenote: Don't use C arrays in C++ code. 1) Besser alternatives exist. 2) C arrays have a lot of idiosyncrasies that "just go away" if you use C++ containers.

A side note on a big mistake: by &buf (not &but, by the way) you pass a pointer, not the address. Internally pointer indeed carries an address, but an address alone is just a location in memory, while a pointer carries also the type of an object pointed at. This allows you to use pointer arithmetics like adding indices to access the next item of an array instead of just a next raw byte in memory.

Concerning that first comment: it's correct, but the more important part is that the next line defines the variable but. Declaring a name says that it exists somewhere (extern int*buf;, for example); defining a name says "here it is". A definition is also a declaration, but a declaration doesn't have to be a definition.

If you're asking why a += buf[c][i]; works, that's because buf is a pointer to the pointer of the first element of the array.
Since the for loop of c only runs for  0 <= c < 1. This line is essentially
a += buf[0][i];

Which is
a += (*buf)[i];

(FYI, in general ptr[i] == *(ptr+i))
i.e you dereference buf to get the pointer to the array, and then dereference the i-th member of the array.
This code has multiple problems
// Declaring a variable:
int* buf = new int[max_size];

Here you should probably use std::array<int, max_size> in C++, if max_size is a compile-time constant. Otherwise std::vector<int>(max_size) is a good choice, this way you don't have to manually manage the memory.
// Filling in the data:
for (int i = 0; i < max_size; ++i) buf[i] += i;

Here, you assume that your array is set to 0 at each element, this is wrong, you should initialize it.
// We pass it to the function:
process(&buf);

Here, there's no reason to pass a pointer to buf as buf is already a pointer.
Your process function should be something like this.
void process(const int* buf)
{
  int a = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < max_size; ++i)
    a += buf[i];
}

I recommend reading about C++ and discovering the languages features.

To understand what's going on you have to learn that for any pointer (or array) p and index i, the expression p[i] is exactly equal to *(p + i).
This comes into play because buf[c] will, with your shown code, always be buf[0], which is the same as *(buf + 0) which is the same as *buf.
So buf[0][i] is the same as (*buf)[i]. That is, you dereference the pointer-to-pointer variable buf to get the original pointer as returned by new[], and then dereference that pointer to get to a specific element.

To show it more graphically and hopefully help you better, inside the process function the variable buf looks something like this:

+-----+     +-----------------------------+     +---+---+---+-----+
| buf | --> | (pointer returned by new[]) | --> | 0 | 1 | 2 | ... |
+-----+     +-----------------------------+     +---+---+---+-----+

When you dereference buf (with either *buf or buf[0]) you go right in the above diagram to "pointer returned by new[]".
When you in turn dereference that pointer (with indexing using i) then you again step right in the diagram, to the corresponding element.


How and by what rule is my array masquerading as an array of arrays?

The code your provided declare buf as a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of ints with a size of max_size. So, buf pointers to the first element of a one-dimensional array of integers.
int* buf = new int[max_size];

In addition, the process function expects a pointer to a pointer to a constant int and the argument being passed to this function is &buf, which has the type int**. Here, buf is of type const int* const*, so buf[c] is dereferencing the first pointer in the array.
void process(const int* const* buf)
{
  int a = 0;
  int ch = 1;
  for(int c = 0; c < ch; ++c)
    for (int i = 0; i < max_size; ++i)
      a += buf[c][i]; // ???
}

